# Convert MySQL query from a nested select to an inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a nested select statement that works as it should, the only problem is  that it takes too long to run.  I converted one of my other queries to an inner join and it is much much faster.  I'm trying to convert this query to an inner join.

Current working  query:

```
select date(datetime), req_origin,  count( distinct session_id)
from LOG L1
where((datetime >= str_to_date('2013-01-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))  
and (datetime < str_to_date('2013-01-05 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
and code_subcode in ('1001111','1001112','1001113','1001114'))
and ((
select count(*) from LOG L2 where  L2.session_id = L1.session_id and date(L2.datetime)
= date(L1.datetime)
and code_subcode in ('1001111','1001112','1001113','1001114')
) = 4)
group by date(datetime),req_origin order by date(datetime),req_origin;
```

This is what I've got for an inner join but  it isn't working properly.  It only returns data when check for 1 matching code.  When I query for 4 matching codes the query doesn't return anything.

```
select date(l1.datetime), l1.req_origin, count(distinct l1.session_id)
from LOG l1
INNER JOIN LOG l2 on l2.SESSION_ID = l1.SESSION_ID
where((l1.datetime >= str_to_date('2013-01-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))  
and (l1.datetime < str_to_date('2013-01-05 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
and l1.code_subcode in ('1001111','1001112','1001113','1001114')
and l2.code_subcode in ('1001111','1001112','1001113','1001114') = 4)
group by date(l1.datetime), l1.req_origin order by date(l1.datetime), l1.req_origin;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution using a join against a subselect.

```
SELECT DATE(datetime), req_origin,  COUNT( DISTINCT session_id)
FROM LOG L1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT session_id, DATE(datetime) AS DateTime, COUNT(*) AS ItemCount
    FROM LOG  
    WHERE code_subcode IN ('1001111','1001112','1001113','1001114')
    GROUP BY session_id, DATE(datetime)
) L2
ON L1.session_id = L2.session_id
AND DATE(L1.datetime) = L2.DateTime
AND ItemCount = 4
WHERE((L1.datetime >= str_to_date('2013-01-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))  
AND (L1.datetime < str_to_date('2013-01-05 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
AND code_subcode IN ('1001111','1001112','1001113','1001114'))
GROUP BY DATE(L1.datetime), req_origin 
ORDER BY DATE(L1.datetime), req_origin;
```

Comment: @kickstar is log L1 and log L2 are diff table ??

Comment: They are both the same table. Given the alias L1 for the main occurrence, while L2 is an alias given to the sub query that is getting the count of items for each session id / date.